# Problem creating CSS background image sprites with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have 2 images that I would like to use as links with a hoverover effect. All over the images and hoverover images exist on a single png file.

The problem I am having is that the first image works just fine, but the second image appears with both the hoverover image beginning at top:0 and the image I want to be seeing directly below it. If I change `#MCD a{` to `#MCD{` then the image displays correctly but all linking functionality for the image disappears.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sites">
<li id="LL"><a href="" /></li>
<li id="MCD"><a href="" /></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#sites{
position:absolute;
margin:0;
padding:0;
top:250px;
left:700px;
width:500px;
background:transparent;
display:block;
}

#sites li{
position:absolute;
list-style:none;
right:0;
}

#LL a{
display:block;
width:442px;
height:43px;
background:url(sitesprites.png) 0 0;
}

#LL a:hover{
background:url(sitesprites.png) 0 -44px;
}
```

**Edited per the responses I have received**

```
#MCD a{
position:absolute;
display:block;
right:0;
top:78px;
width:384px;
height:54px;
background:url(sitesprites.png) left -88px;
}

#MCD a:hover{
background-position:left -143px;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lipestyle/77a2z/

Comment: The `<a>` inside the "MCD" element does not have "position: absolute", so I'm not sure what you expect the "top" and "right" to do for that.

Comment: I have fixed this and included a jsfiddle for your review. Any help you guys can offer will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML I'm not sure what you exact problem is, except the the hover is not working correctly.

As Pointy said, in order for top and right to work you must declare the element to be position absolute (which will remove it from the flow of the page.)

Also how are your pngs made? Is on image on top of the other or is it side by side? The syntax for background position is horizontal first then vertical positioning. (kind of backwards.) Most browsers will parse backwards syntax ( `background-position: top center`;) if you use top, bottom, left, right, or center. But when using numbers they have to be in the right order.

Your numbers look a little weird. Usually css sprites are done vertically and positioned `background-position: top;` then moved the height of the `<a>` (which would be half the total height of the PNG) down on the hover.

Assuming the height of your `<a>` is half the height of the PNG image and your PNGs are vertical, try something like this:

```
#MCD a{
  display: block; 
  width:384px;
  height:54px;
  background:url(sitesprites.png) left top;
}

#MCD a:hover{
  background-position: left -54px; /* just use background position instead of redefining the image */
}
```

just a side not, you should always try to use your css sprites on the `<a>` element.

Comment: How stupid of me to forget the HTML, here it is: 
`<ul id="sites"> <li id="LL"><a href="" /></li> <li id="MCD"><a href="" /></li> </ul>` @Pointy thanks for pointing out the missing "position:absolute." I thought that because it was under #sites li{ that it would apply to evetrything. @jlego my sprite image has them right on top of each other, so your code worked well. Now that I have added position:absolute to MCD it seemed to clear up the double images being on above each other, but now they are just stacked on top of each other in the correct position.

Comment: If this doesn't make sense, I can try to get the site online somewhere so I can link to it :-/